# How do I configure IBM IMS connector in JBoss

Tags: jboss, ims-db, ims-tm

I have the IMS Connector RAR file. Placed it inside JBOSS_INSTALL/server/default/deploy directory. Created a ims-ds.xml file and also placed in the same location. It appears as if it is deploying with this message:

21:40:02,800 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/ims225Connector.rar/

But then it gives the following error:

--- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM ---
ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=MHAccountDetailsAXIS.war,id=258164183
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Error during deploy; - nested throwable: (javax.naming.NamingException: resource-ref: eis/IMSCZ has no valid JNDI binding. Check the jboss-web/resource-ref.)

ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name=IMS Connector for Java
  State: NOTYETINSTALLED
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.jca:service=NoTxDS,name=eis/IMSCZ

Answer (score 1):

Added jboss-web.xml that provides  a mapping between JNDI and resource-ref name and finally got it going.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to proceed further after correcting the IMS-ds.xml file. Next I got:
Unable to invoke setter method 'public void com.ibm.connector2.ims.ico.IMSManagedConnectionFactory.setMFSXMIRepositoryID(java.lang.String)' on object 'com.ibm.connector2.ims.ico.IMSManagedConnectionFactory@0'; - nested throwable: (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet)

Next I download the eclipse jar files:org.eclipse.emf.common_2.4.0.v200808251517.jar and
org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.4.1.v200808251517.jar and place in the same location as the IMS RAR and get past that error.

I see the JNDI being established:
12:02:28,082 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=eis/IMSCZ' to JNDI name 'java:eis/IMSCZ'

But then I get this error:
12:02:28,941 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss.web.deployment:war=MHAccountDetailsAXIS.war,id=1972990498
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Error during deploy; - nested throwable: (javax.naming.NamingException: resource-ref: eis/IMSCZ has no valid JNDI binding. Check the jboss-web/resource-ref.)

What else should I define to get this going?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to configure IBM IMS TM Resource adapter on JBOSS. You can use one of the method in installation.

a. Using command prompt

b. Use web console

[localhost:9990/console](http://localhost:9990/console)

c. Changing standalone.xml configuration file.

I used 3rd approach for other approach refer link
[Configuring IMS TM resource adapter](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Configure_a_Deployed_Resource_Adapter1.html)

Here are the steps to configure

Sptep 1: Download IMS TM RA using below link (You first need to register with IBM to be able to download adapter)
[IMS TM Resource Adapter](https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/reg/download.do?source=imscjd&lang=en_US&S_PKG=14&cp=UTF-8)

Step 2: Extract the ico1322.zip (which you downloaded from step 1) in below folder.

jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules

Note: Some of the IMS adapter are already part of JBOSS installation, So please cross check whether the adapter is already available by default.

Step 3: Edit jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml file.

Edit below section and add following XML

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0">
```

Replace the place holders  ${XXXXXXXXX}

```
<resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="ims1322.rar">
            <archive>ims1321.rar</archive>
              <!--  <module slot="main" id="com.ibm.connector2"/>-->
                <transaction-support>LocalTransaction</transaction-support>
                <config-property name="threadContextPropagationRequired">
                    false
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="adapterID">
                    IMSTM
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="enableHASupport">
                    true
                </config-property>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.connector2.ims.ico.IMSManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:jboss/ims/DAS_IMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY" enabled="true" use-java-context="false" pool-name="java:jboss/ims/DAS_IMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY">
                        <config-property name="CM0Dedicated">
                            FALSE
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="SSLEnabled">
                            FALSE
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="SSLEncryptionType">
                            Weak
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="DataStoreName">
                           ${XXXXXXXXX}
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="Password">
                         ${XXXXXXXXX}
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="UserName">
                         ${XXXXXXXXX} 
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="PortNumber">
                             ${XXXXXXXXX}
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="TraceLevel">
                            1
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="HostName">
                             ${XXXXXXXXX}
                        </config-property>
                        <pool>
                            <min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
                            <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
                            <prefill>false</prefill>
                            <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                            <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                        </pool>
                        <security>
                            <application/>
                        </security>
                        <validation>
                            <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                        </validation>
                   </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
            </resource-adapter>
            </resource-adapters>
```

Step 4:

```
 <resource-adapter id="ims1322.rar">
```

The above tag should have the same rar(If you unzip the ims1322.zip file, you will find ims1322.rar file) which we had downloaded in step 1

Step 5: Start the server in standalone mode.

```
jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>standalone.bat
```

Step 6: Check console whether the adapter is installed in profile --> Resource adapter link

[localhost:9990/console](http://localhost:9990/console)